# What are the aws iam policies for ListDiscoveredResources and ListResource Functions

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-policies

What are the aws iam  policies for ListDiscoveredResources and ListResource Functions? When I tried from aws cli, its returning the error *user is not authorised to perform:config:listDiscoveredResources* for list discovered resource and *user is not authorised to perform:config:ram:ListResources on resource* for list resource

Answer (score 0):

It's is AWS Config Service Role Policy